# .pam_environment not applied on first login but applied on successive logins

Tags: ecryptfs, pam-environment

I have a `~/.pam_environment` file. When I start my computer and login, those environment variables are not applied, but when I logout and login again they are applied.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using encrypted home directories using ecryptfs, then perhaps the system attempts to read `~/.pam_environment` before unlocking your home directory.

Here's a workaround which makes the file unencrypted. You will need `sudo` powers.

1. Close all programs, because some programs are going to crash using this method.
2. Open a terminal.
3. Go to your home directory by running `cd`
4. Move the file to the unencrypted `~/.ecryptfs` directory by running `mv .pam_environment .ecryptfs/`
5. Make the file accessible from the decrypted environment: `ln -s .ecryptfs/.pam_environment`
6. Exit the decrypted environment by running `ecryptfs-umount-private`. Although you will likely get a "*Sessions still open, not unmounting*" warning, it seems that the exiting still worked. You can confirm by attempting to run `ecryptfs-umount-private` again.

   Your decrypted home directory is now not accessible, and it is normal to get lots of errors on your terminal because programs (e.g. shells) weren't built for this. You should be able to continue nonetheless. Avoid starting programs as much as possible until you reboot in step 8.
7. Make the file accessible from the non-decrypted environment by running `sudo ln -s ~/.ecryptfs/.pam_environment`.
8. Reboot your computer. You should now hopefully have `.pam_environment` applied from the first login.

Related link:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/584249
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/1748036

Comment: (Per StackExchange policy, it is ~fine~ encouraged to self-answer your questions if you want to document a solution to a problem you had: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)